Should we hold a community event in the chat?
There's a chat room for our site and I was just talking to AshRj, wondering how to promote the chat itself. He suggested holding a community event. A moderator would have to create it, but we could organize it amongst ourselves.
Not only would using the chat more foster the community spirit, I think it may also be a good way of getting to know each other.
What do you think? Should we hold a community event, perhaps discussing RCE topics, perhaps discussing how to promote the site, perhaps just aligning on topics such as the FAQ discussion here on meta and others?

Sounds like a great idea and it will probably also speed up resolving some open FAQ questions. Just as a note: it should probably be held on Saturday or Sunday for timezone reasons. Looking forward to it!

I think it would be great if we could get industry professionals to hold scheduled Q&A sessions live in the chat-room or even a small presentation on interesting tidbits that they've come across.  

Weekly Meet has been scheduled starting from 14:00 UTC every Saturday. Register yourself here!

To decide on the time for the event, add your preference to this schedule.
Add your preference under your SE username, and add multiple suitable preferences. 
The event, once scheduled will be a weekly event.


The event has been scheduled. Hope to see you there!
See the schedule for the time in your time zone. Dont forget to register for the event!


@AshRj so how should we promote it? Are there means for putting up a banner or the likes at the top of RE.SE or maybe in the side bar?

@justsome The event shows up in the Community Bulletin a few hours before the event as well as on the main page. Other than that, its simply about spreading the word. Post the event link under people's posts (those who may be interested). (Be sure to delete them later on once the OP responds)

@AshRj: so how does this work if I can't attend a particular instance of the meeting, such as this upcoming weekend?

@0xC0000022L There is nothing extra that you have to do. However, do drop a message in chat stating this, if you know in advance.

Could it be shifted 2 hours later, for those of us on the pacific coast who don't get up that early?

@MMavipc We are going with an entirely new time. Add whatever suits you most.

@AsheeshR Are you ever going to update the doodle with times that suit other people?

@MMavipc 0xC0000022L is handling the doodle. Its better if you ping him to add more time slots.
